# Fill between many pairs of points

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plotly

If I run the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'start': [0, 3, 7], 'end': [1, 4, 8]})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in df.index:
    ax.fill_betweenx([0, 1], df.loc[i, 'start'], df.loc[i, 'end'], color='red')
```

I get this output, as expected:
[image]

The problem with the code I've written is that, if I have a huge dataframe, then looping through all the rows takes a long time.

Is there a faster way of achieving the same output?

matplotlib or plotly solutions welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `fill_between` instead of `fill_betweenx`, you can do

```
boundaries = df[['start', 'end', 'end']].to_numpy().ravel()

ax.fill_between(
    boundaries,
    np.zeros(len(boundaries)),
    np.ones(len(boundaries)),
    where=np.tile([True, True, False], len(df)),
    color='red'
)
```

Comment: Great idea - I had all the knowledge necessary to come up with this solution, but didn't. Thanks!